# how to hide and show button in asp.net core razor page which are not have run at Server command in c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I have two buttons on the asp.net core razor page as shown below code:

```
 <div class="row div-form-control">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group actions">
                        
                        <button type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" action="save"><i class="icon-floppy-disk position-right"></i>Submit</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" action="search"><i class="icon-new-tab position-left"></i>Search</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
 </div>
```

now I want to hide Submit Button in C# when the User Role is not an Admin like:

```
string Role="NormalUser";
if(Role!="Admin"){
 submit.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

but it does not work because in submit button I don't have Runat="Server" I want to hide it without using Ranat="Server" by JavaScript or Another Method Can anyone help me how to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one way to do it is like:

```
@if(Role!="Admin"){
    <button type="button" name="submit" style="display:hidden;" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" action="save"><i class="icon-floppy-disk position-right"></i>Submit</button>
}else{
    <button type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" action="save"><i class="icon-floppy-disk position-right"></i>Submit</button>
}
```

Comment: how  the IF and Else conditions work in HTML???

Comment: it works with an @ in front of the if. 
I updated my answer.

Maybe this will help you:
[Razor Syntax on ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-6.0)